# How to create a controller on Dart using Maps and Lists?

Tags: firebase, list, dart, controller, checkboxlist

I've got this code where I'm displaying multiple CheckboxListTile widgets on my screen. I need to create a controller for them, but I'm having some trouble. Could you help me? Thanks in advance.
I have already the Model, entity, mapper and so on in order to use the Clean architecture.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ClinicHistoryController extends GetxController {
  final ClinicHistoryRepository clinicHistoryImpl;
  ClinicHistoryController(this.clinicHistoryImpl);
  List<ClinicHistory> clinicHistoryList = [];

  List<BoolItemElectronicFile> familyHeritageData = [
    BoolItemElectronicFile(name: "Cancer", value: false),
    BoolItemElectronicFile(name: "Cardiopatías", value: false),
    BoolItemElectronicFile(name: "Diabetes", value: false),
    BoolItemElectronicFile(name: "Hepatopatías", value: false),
    BoolItemElectronicFile(name: "Hipertensión", value: false),
    BoolItemElectronicFile(name: "Obesidad", value: false),
    BoolItemElectronicFile(name: "Osteoporosis", value: false),
  ];
  List<ItemElectronicFile> pathologiesdata = [
  //items
  ];
  List<ItemElectronicFile> symptomsPresentingdata = [
    //items
  ];
  MedicalTreatments medicalTreatmentsdata =
      MedicalTreatments(medicalTreatments: " ");

  PerformedSurgeries performedSurgeriesdata =
      PerformedSurgeries(performedSurgeries: " ");

//moreitems
  

  handleHereditarydata(dynamic newValue) {
    familyHeritageData = newValue;
    update();
  }

  handlesufferingPathologies(dynamic newValue) {
    pathologiesdata = newValue;
    update();
  }
handlesymptoms(dynamic newValue) {
    pathologiesdata = newValue;
    update();
  }

  Future addClinicHistory() async {
    final newClinicHistory = ClinicHistory(
        familyHeritageData: familyHeritageData,
        sufferingPathologies: pathologiesdata,
        symptomsPresenting: symptomsPresentingdata,
        medicalTreatments: medicalTreatmentsdata,
        performedSurgeries: performedSurgeriesdata,
        //moreitems
        );
    try {
      await clinicHistoryImpl
          .addClinicHistory(history: newClinicHistory, idUser: "ADFGSDF")
          .then(
            (value) => Get.snackbar("Nuevo metodo de pago", "Pago registrado.",
                backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 5)),
          );
      update();
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar('Invalido', 'Invalido',
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 5));
    }
  }
}
```

This is the implementation file:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ClinicHistoryDatasourceFirebase implements ClinicHistoryDataSource {
  CollectionReference clinicHistoryref =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Expediente');

  @override
  Future addClinicHistory(
      {required ClinicHistory history, required String idUser}) async {
    await clinicHistoryref
        .doc(idUser)
        .set(ClinicHistoryFileMapper.toJson(history))
        .whenComplete(() => Get.snackbar(
            "Nuevo Expediente Electronico", "Expediente registrado.",
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 5)))
        .catchError((error, stackTrace) {
      Get.snackbar("Error", "Intentalo de nuevo",
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 5));
      print(error.toString());
    });
    return clinicHistoryref;
  }
```

Comment: "I need to create a controller for them, but I'm having some trouble." What trouble are you having? Is there an error message? If so, which specific line of the code you shared is giving what exact error message? If there's no error message, it might help if you debug the code and tell us the result. So if you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?